# Unifying CMake's FIND_PACKAGE

Tags: cmake

Do you know a trick to get a unified output terminology when getting include and library paths from CMake's FIND_PACKAGE?

Sometimes it's FOO_INCLUDE. Sometimes it's FOO_INCLUDE_PATH. Etc.

For example, I would like to find a way to ensure that FOO_INCLUDE and FOO_LIB be always defined when FOO_FOUND is set to TRUE after a call to FIND_PACKAGE.

Comment: Modern find package's implementation do provide IMPORTED targets like `Foo::Foo` (to avoid the need to know the include path, library, etc. dependencies and their variable notations).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Florian. Could you give me an example of such an imported target? As far as I understand CMake's documentation of FIND_PACKAGE function, these targets are supposed to be defined in FindFOO.cmake files but it is not always the case (e.g. FindMPI). Therefore, saying that unification is reachable through imported targets may be true, but it is currently false to argue that it is unified. Thus, it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Except from `FOO_FOUND` and some special "find" variables, CMake **doesn't enforce `Find` scripts to set specific variables**. So answer to your question would be `No, there is no unified way.` However, you may write your own function/macro for post process result of `find_package`. In that function you may check common patterns (*FOO_INCLUDE*, *FOO_INCLUDE_PATH*, *FOO_INCLUDE_DIR* and so on) and set desired variable to appropriate value.

Comment: Thank you Tsyvarev. That's what I did. I hope this part of CMake will be improved in the future.

Answer (score 1):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

To avoid the need to know the include path, library, etc. dependencies and their variable notations modern `find_package`'s implementation do provide `IMPORTED` targets like `Foo::Foo`. But this is - as @Tsyvarev has commented - far from unified through all of CMake's [find modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-modules.7.html).

So generalizing the [CMake's Sample Find Module implementation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-developer.7.html?highlight=notfound#a-sample-find-module) you could unify your `find_package()` calls with an overwritten `find_package()` macro version like the following:

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

project(UnifiedFindPackage)

macro(unify_vars _result)
    set(${_result} "")
    foreach(_i IN ITEMS ${ARGN})
        if (${_i})
            list(APPEND ${_result} "${${_i}}")
        endif()
    endforeach()
endmacro()

macro(find_package _name)
    _find_package(${_name} ${ARGN})
    if (${_name}_FOUND AND NOT TARGET ${_name}::${_name})
        add_library(${_name}::${_name} STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
        unify_vars(_var ${_name}_LIBRARY ${_name}_LIB)
        if (_var)
            set_target_properties(${_name}::${_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${_var}")
        endif()
        if (${_name}_LIBRARY_RELEASE)
            set_property(TARGET ${_name}::${_name} APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELEASE)
            set_target_properties(${_name}::${_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${${_name}_LIBRARY_RELEASE}")
        endif()
        if (${_name}_LIBRARY_DEBUG)
            set_property(TARGET ${_name}::${_name} APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS DEBUG)
            set_target_properties(${_name}::${_name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG "${${_name}_LIBRARY_DEBUG}")
        endif()            
        if (${_name}_LIBRARIES)
            set_property(TARGET ${_name}::${_name} APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "${${_name}_LIBRARIES}")
        endif()
        unify_vars(_var ${_name}_INCLUDE_DIRS ${_name}_INCLUDE_PATH)
        if (_var)
            set_property(TARGET ${_name}::${_name} APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_var}")
        endif()
        unify_vars(_var ${_name}_COMPILE_FLAGS ${_name}_DEFINITIONS)
        if (_var)
            set_property(TARGET ${_name}::${_name} APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "${_var}")
        endif()
    endif()            
endmacro()

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} MPI::MPI)
```

This should only demonstrate a possible unification and could be extended on a need-by basis.

**Edit:** Turning this into an community wiki answer. Please feel free to contribute.

The code was tested in this example with `MPI` find module results.

Comment: Thnak you very much! I will test your solution today and make a reply here.